# Rombo de asteriscos en php

Tags: php

Necesito invertir este secuencia para crear un rombo, para que se muestre la misma secuencia debajo pero ahora invertido:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código:

```
<?php
  echo "<center>";
  for ($i=0; $i< 4; $i++) {
    for ($k=0; $k<4; $k++) {
        echo str_repeat(' * ', $k + $i++ + 1); // La sumatoria se realiza para que la siguiente iteracion del arbol empiece en **
        echo "<br>";
    }
  }     
?>
```

Comment: Y cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: Tengo dudas de cómo invertir el for para que me muestre lo mismo pero invertido y así crear el rombo

Comment: Intenta invertir el recorrido de los `for` y edita tu pregunta con lo que intentaste

Answer (score 1):

Puedes simplificarlo de esta manera:

```
<?php
    echo "<center>";
    for($i=0, $j=1; $i<4; $i++, $j++) {
        echo str_repeat(" * ", $i + $j).'<br />';
    }
    for($i=3, $j=2; $i>0; $i--, $j--) {
        echo str_repeat(" * ", $i + $j).'<br />';
    }
    echo "</center>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Usando la función integrada [str_repeat](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-repeat.php)

Puedes poner la cantidad de asteriscos que quieras en la variable `$max`.
 
[ Nota ] - Funciona en consola. Pero si es para web, agregas el salto `<br />` antes de `PHP_EOL`. Adicional html no te va a reconocer así por así varios espacios seguidos. En ese caso puedes usar `&nbsp;` en vez de espacios en el código.

```
<?php
$max = 5;
for($i=0;$i<=$max;++$i) {
    echo str_repeat(' ', $max-$i) . str_repeat("* ", $i).PHP_EOL;
}
for($i=$max-1;$i>0;--$i) {
    echo str_repeat(' ', $max-$i) . str_repeat("* ", $i).PHP_EOL;
}
```